# Removing and then adding back a device in Devices and Printers using PowerShell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, automation, powershell-3.0

Background: My TV which is listed as "Bravia KDL-32EX720" in "Devices and Printers" (in Control Panel) grays out and thus stops responding to "Play To" DLNA commands. The only solution that I know is removing and re-adding the TV. The process is like this:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Devices and Printers.
2. Right-clicking on "Bravia KDL-32EX720."
3. Click on "Remove Device" and yes on the confirmation prompt.
4. Once it's removed, click on "Add Device" button in the same window "Devices and Printers."
5. Wait for the list of available devices to appear.
6. The TV shows up here. Add it by double-clicking on it.

Now, I want to automate this process because I have to do it repeatedly*.

I know a bit of PowerShell and know that the window Devices and Printers can be opened by this command:

```
control printers
```

But, I don't know how to proceed after this. Please guide me in making a script for the full task. And I would not mind if instead a script in Python or AutoHotKey is provided. I use Windows 8 64-bit Pro. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot taken while I was removing the device]

**Each time I turn off and turn on my TV, I have to go through the process. I have gone through all the steps provided to me on Microsoft Answers to fix this problem (running SFC, restarting some services etc.)  but none of them have helped.*

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath. The add device wizard is dynamic (searches for devices), so I'm not sure that this could easily be scripted..

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction.aspx) help?

Comment: No, I am unable to find the TV by using Get-Device. I guess that's because my TV doesn't show up in the Device Manager, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably automate this using [MS UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx) from a Powershell script.

Here's a hello world UIA Powershell script to get an idea of how to get started:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\UIAutomationClient.dll')
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\UIAutomationTypes.dll')

# Get the root/desktop element
$rootElement = [Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::RootElement
# Print its Name and ClassName
Write-Host "Note: In the managed UIA API, the desktop name is empty:"
"'" + $rootElement.Current.Name + "'"
Write-Host "Instead, you can identify the desktop by its ClassName, #32769:"
"'" + $rootElement.Current.ClassName + "'"
```

To go beyond that, you might benefit from the WASP Powershell snapin, although it doesn't seem to have been updated in a while:

http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Also, since for this project you want to automate the UI of the control panel, it's highly likely that you'll need to execute the script with "Run as Administrator" privileges. Without that, making changes to the control panel is unlikely to work.